# How to fix the Threejs webxr examples for wide FOV displays?

Tags: three.js, virtual-reality, webvr, webxr

Threejs has some webxr examples but they all seem to assume the user will be using a small FOV headset and use parallel projections. When you view them on a wide FOV headset with canted displays (like a Pimax) the 3D objects for the left/right eye do not line up. This can be fixed by enabling parallel projections compatibility in PiTools but this causes a performance hit.

Here is an example that does this: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=WebXR#webxr_vr_cubes

I've been told that newer games engines don't have this problem because they no longer assume a narrow FOV headset will be used and make the appropriate adjustments.

My question is what changes would need to be made to the example code for the demo to support the Pimax or other wide FOV headsets?